# Tryning to do a SOQL in my class to retrieve records from a range of Dates

Tags: apex, soql, query

I'm trying to get just records that the end date is > than 2 years ago, but I couldn't find a way. That is what I've tried, but it just return the records until today, and I have to get the contracts with future EndDate as well.

```
SELECT Id, EndDate FROM Contract WHERE EndDate = LAST_N_DAYS:730 ORDER BY EndDate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date literals can be used with > and < operators to include times outside that range. Use < for dates older than the specified range, and > for dates after the range.

```
SELECT Id, EndDate FROM Contract WHERE EndDate >= LAST_N_DAYS:730 ORDER BY EndDate
```